# Migrating to React Query 3

Tags: reactjs, react-typescript, react-query

I'm trying to type the argument of the `getMenu(key)` function, it was originally a string, but after migrating to 3.0, it forces me to make the key a `QueryFunctionContext<any, any>` type, but I need a string like before. Have any ideas ? Thanks!

```
export const getMenu = async (key: string): Promise<IMenuItemData> => {
  try {
    const payload = await axios.get(key);
    return payload.data;
  } catch (reason) {
    throw parseError(reason);
  }
};

export const useMenu = (slug: string): UseQueryResult<IMenuPayload, IServerErrorObject> => {
  return useQuery<IMenuPayload, TError, IMenuPayload>(
    `menu/${slug}`,
----------> (key: string): Promise<IMenuPayload> => getMenu(key)
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

in v3, the query key is no longer spread directly into your query function. Now, a `QueryContext` is passed, but this does not work very well with TypeScript because of the dynamic nature of queryKeys.

The recommended approach is an inline function:

```
export const useMenu = (slug: string): UseQueryResult<IMenuPayload, IServerErrorObject> => {
  const key = `menu/${slug}`
  return useQuery<IMenuPayload, TError, IMenuPayload>(
    key,
    () => getMenu(key)
  );
};
```

The idea is that in the function where you create the `useQuery`, you have to know what the `queryKey` is anyways, so you can just closure over it. Also, you don't need to additionally type that function - it will be nicely inferred for you.